# Add Mathjax to Ethereum.SE

Tags: feature-request

I'm reading [Gavin Wood's yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/Paper.pdf). I anticipate asking some questions on the formulae.

**Would it be worthwhile adding [MathJax functionality](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to the Ethereum StackExchange site?**

Or do you think I should post such questions to another community?

Comment: This would be great. It wouldn't be useful only for questions related to the Yellow Paper, but also for DeFi. Many protocols employ hard-core maths in their design, e.g. [Uniswap V3](https://uniswap.org/blog/uniswap-v3/).

Answer (score 5):

The devs are generally unwilling to add dependencies unless the community can demonstrate a need. Therefore, the general process for adding MathJax to a site is to find around a dozen or more posts which would benefit from its presence. It would be better if these were not all by the same person.

So start asking, and hope others do similarly. Once there are a few posts which are struggling to include mathematics, and which would clearly be improved by MathJax, ask again. Include a list of such posts in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?Ethereum\cdot\frac{Stack}{Exchange}
```

Result:

[image: Ethereum Stack Exchange]

Play around here: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

We should reconsider this when there is a broader need. For now, it's pretty convinient to just use external tools. Also see this heavy debate on main meta: [LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: codecogs site not working at present